# Blank results on json parse on https api calling using php and MAMP

Tags: php, json

I´m trying a very simple php script which is about calling a json data through api calling on a online https link using MAMP.
However if I use the following code I have blank results:

```
<?php
$cnmkt = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=50";
$json = file_get_contents($cnmkt);
$fgc = json_decode($json,true);
echo $fgc[1]['percent_change_7d'];
?>
```

But if i copy/paste the content of the https link into a test.json file locally, substituting the https link with the test.json file on $cnmkt variable, the same exact script works properly.
I know i´m missing something very obvious, if someone could help me that would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

The script is working fine. I get an expected result of `4.63`

Disable your AV/firewall and check again.

Comment: Thanks for the message, I had no luck with your suggestion. I tried disabling firewall, adblocker, change browser etc. When I execute the script it stays in "waiting for localhost" until the connection in dropped. If i paste the https link in the browser i am able to retrieve the content. Do you have any further suggestion? thanks

Comment: Turnoff any other application that could be listening on port 80 and restart Apache. Example Skype, some download manager. 
The problem is not in your script, but your network somewhere.